# Querying a meteor collection by checking whether a sub field exists

Tags: jquery, meteor

I have a meteor collection I am working with.

Every object in this collection has a field which is an array of objects. This array of objects is not the same for every object in my main collection. Sometimes, this field has two objects, sometime three and so on.

In my query, I want to check if any of these objects in the array contain a particular field and return only those objects from my main collection which do.

How would I write this query?

Comment: Please include a sample of the documents being queried and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

Given the document:

```
{
  array: [
    {
      optionalField: ""
      otherField: ""
    }
  ]
}
```

in the Widgets collection,

```
Widgets.find({'array.optionalField': {$exists : true }})
```

would return all the Widget documents where the optionalField existed.

As you can probably glean from the example, the Mongo '$exists' query operator selects only the documents containing that field, whether it is otherwise falsy or not.